# Declaring functions / variables automatically

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Is it possible to declare functions or variables automatically in Webstorm? I have following code

```
switch(VAL){
  case 0:
    FUNC1();   //undeclared
    FUNC2()    //undeclared
    break;
  case 1:
   .... many more ..
}
```

When I hover over on each function, it says

> Unresolved function or method FUNC1()..

I want to figure out a way to declare functions in following pattern

```
function FUNC1(){

}

function FUNC2(){

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try pressing `Alt+Enter` when your cursor is inside undeclared function call, and you will get a list of possible actions, among them declaring the new function as local/global etc.

[image]